# How to check multiple Switch case value in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, switch-statement

In **Swift** it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43058881/1084174) to check a tuple like,

```
switch(type1, type2) {
    case (1, 1):
        functionNormal()
    case (1, 2):
        functionUncommon()
    case (1, 3):
        functionRare()
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to check tuple like multiple values in **Objective-C** Switch case? **Any way around?**

Comment: I think tuple was not defined in objective-c, then you can't!

Comment: @ArashEtemad I know tuple is not defined in objective-c but any way around?

Comment: you should go through the switch by one value then use another switch or if-else in each case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be various approaches, depending on exactly what your `type1` and `type2` data might be.

However, here is a basic example:

```
NSInteger i = 1;
NSInteger j = 2;

switch (i) {
    case 1:
        switch (j) {
            case 1:
                [self functionNormal];
                break;

            case 2:
                [self functionUncommon];
                break;

            case 3:
                [self functionRare];
                break;

            default:
                NSLog(@"first value: 1 ... missing case for second value: for %ld", (long)j);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case 2:
        switch (j) {
            case 1:
                [self secondFunctionNormal];
                break;

            case 2:
                [self secondFunctionUncommon];
                break;

            case 3:
                [self secondFunctionRare];
                break;

            default:
                NSLog(@"first value: 2 ... missing case for second value: %ld", (long)j);
                break;
        }
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"missing first case for first value: %ld", (long)i);
        break;
}
```

This is rather inefficient, of course, but maybe it can get you on your way.

---

**Edit**

Again, it will depend on your data, but another approach more closely resembling your Swift example:

```
NSInteger i = 1;
NSInteger j = 2;

NSInteger ij = i * 1000 + j;

switch (ij) {
    case 1001:
        [self functionNormal];
        break;

    case 1002:
        [self functionUncommon];
        break;

    case 1003:
        [self functionRare];
        break;

    case 2001:
        [self secondFunctionNormal];
        break;

    case 2002:
        [self secondFunctionUncommon];
        break;

    case 2003:
        [self secondFunctionRare];
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"case was something else: %ld", (long)ij);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Although impractical, your second option is not theoretically 100% accurate because it might end up with a conflict for `i=0, j=1000` with `i=1, j = 0` and it worth mentioning in your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan - exactly, which is why I stated ***depending on exactly what your type1 and type2 data might be.*** For that specific example, you would multiply `I` by a higher value than the max that `j` could reach. Probably worth repeating: ***There could be various approaches*** - neither of these is what *I* would do, but I believe it answers the question of *"Any way around?"*